# my navigation drawer shows below my gridview

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

the other day , i create a navigation drawer of the android examples , but this shows below my gridview.

[image]

The code is from the example , I dont know what happend

fragment_navigation_drawer.xml

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f3f3f3"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
tools:context="es.example.NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

fragment_drawer.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="es.example.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
android:background="#f3f3f3" >
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/lst"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="120dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:layout_marginLeft=".5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop=".5dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="" />
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

Comment: Where is the layout file which actually include the DrawerLayout?

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Show your code in `PlaceholderFragment`, can't reproduce from just the xml layout.

Comment: show full main layout so it can give idea how u placed drawer and other views.